# Want the height of ControlsFX SpreadsheetView to the total of the rowheight

Tags: javafx-8, controlsfx

I want the height of the spreadsheetview to be as long as the total rows in it.
that is if there are 3 rows of 30,40,50 height the height of spreadsheetview should be 120, i want the rowheight to be AUTOFIT, as i wrap text on few cells.
the getRowHeight returns AUTOFIT, but i want the actual height of the cell or row as the row is as high the highest cell.

Answer (score 0):

The getRowHeight on the Grid will indeed returns AUTOFIT because the grid is the model and what's intended.

But if you do call getRowHeight on the SpreadsheetView itself (the skin must be created), you will get the row height as requested :

```
 for(int i=0;i<spreadSheetView.getGrid().getRowCount(); i++){
                    System.out.println(spreadSheetView.getRowHeight(i));
                }
```